# How can I refactor this code for fetching Mongo Data from an Array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6, async-await

```
let arrayOfDocuments = await Promise.all(result.data.CompanyCodes.map(async (eachCompany) => {
  let corporate = await Organization.findOne({ codeOfCompany: eachCompany });
  return corporate;
}));
```

I would like to know if there's a better way to refactor the above code.

Comment: "Better" how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with `$in` in Mongo Query:

```
let arrayOfDocuments = await Organization.find({ 
    codeOfCompany: { '$in': result.data.CompanyCodes }
})
```

Document here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/. This query check if field `codeOfCompany` is exist in array of values `result.data.CompanyCodes`.